# how to add column with key and value in json mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to update new key and value in address inner json. I tried but I cannot update the new key and value in existing objects.

```js
var mongodb=require("mongodb");
var mongoclient=mongodb.MongoClient;
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/details";
mongoclient.connect(url,function(err,db)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log("unable to connect database");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("details database connected successfully");
        var collection=db.collection("users");
        collection.update({"name":"naranyamoorthy"}, {$addtoset: {"address[country]":"USA"}},function(err,result)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log("not updated");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("updated succesfully");
                console.log();
                db.close();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The JSONFILE contains:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58956389362992d7976510d4"),
    "name" : "naranyamoorthy",
    "age" : 21,
    "subject" : [
        "Bootstrap",
        "node.js",
        "j2ee",
        "javascript"
    ],
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Afganistan",
        "state" : "tamilnadu",
        "pincode" : "12352"
    }
}
```

I need:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58956389362992d7976510d4"),
    "name" : "naranyamoorthy",
    "age" : 21,
    "subject" : [
        "Bootstrap",
        "node.js",
        "j2ee",
        "javascript"
    ],
    "address" : {
        "city" : "chennai",
        "state" : "tamilnadu",
        "pincode" : "12352",
        "country":"India"
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend two approaches: Firstly, construct the right query in the mongo shell, and then build your code to do the same query. That will help you get your query right. Secondly, run your code through a debugger; that will help solve the problems in your code such as variables not being set.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct, if you want to set country which is inside address then use `address.country` instead of `address[country]`. Here is the corrected query:

```
var mongodb=require("mongodb");
var mongoclient=mongodb.MongoClient;
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/details";
mongoclient.connect(url,function(err,db)
{
  if(err)
  {
    console.log("unable to connect database");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("details database connected successfully");
    var collection=db.collection("users");
    collection.update({"name":"naranyamoorthy"}, {$set:{"address.country":"USA"}},function(err,result)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("not updated");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("updated succesfully");
            console.log();
            db.close();
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not  working. It shows $addtoset  as a unknown identifier

Comment: Sorry, It's must be $addToSet instead of $addtoset, updated the code.

Comment: It is working but it couldn't update perfectly.It updated "country" : ["USA"]  in address json.It printed including angular bracket.I need without angular bracket.

Comment: So you should use $set instead of $addToSet because $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.